# JavaScript is not loaded although it exists in the artifact in the correct path

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I am trying to run an xhtml page which uses a javascript file named flotr2.js file.  [image]

This is the original script tag:

```
    1- <script type="text/javascript" src="../../resources/flotr2_master/flotr2.js"></script>

I also tried the following script tags:

 2- <script type="text/javascript" src="/localhost/enterprisesecvis/resources/flotr2_master/flotr2.js"></script>

 3-<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/enterprisesecvis/resources/flotr2_master/flotr2.js"></script>

 4-<script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}//resources/flotr2_master/flotr2.js"></script>
```

The script definitions 1,3 and 4 forms a correct link for the JS file. The script definition 2 forms an incorrect path.

All four definitions ended with 404 error :(

This js file is in the following directory
Project_root\Project_Name\out\artifacts\war_name_exploded\resources\flotr2_master

The link that the explorer tries to load the Js file is

http://localhost:8090/Project_Name/resources/flotr2_master/flotr2.js

Explorer loads the all xhtml pages correctly using a link such as below

http://localhost:8090/Project_Name/pages/folder/aaa.xhtml

The error which explorer developer tool shows is "flotr2.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

This is the picture of explorer searching for the path. This view also shows that the path is not wrong for the js file.
[image]

I can not continue to my code due to this error. Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you

Ferda

Comment: Can you post the script tag? It's difficult to help with so little information.

Comment: Hello Archer, thank you for your interest. I updated my question. Is it what you were asking for?

Comment: I don't see a script tag in there.

Comment: I marked it as code now you can see it.

Comment: That looks fine to me. Try changing the path to this.. /localhost:8090/Project_Name/resources/flotr2_master/flotr2.js

Comment: Make sure to have the forward slash at the beginning.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8090/enterprisesecvis/resources/flotr2_master/flotr2.js"></script>

Comment: I updated as this one still can not load :(

Comment: When I update with /localhost bla bla bla the path for the js file becomes http://localhost:8090/localhost:8090/enterprisesecvis/resources/flotr2_master/flotr2.js which is totally wrong. So I updated with "http://localhost/enterprisesecvis bla bla bla " that way the link that explorer searchs for is correct. But it still can not load giving 404 error.

Comment: localhost:8090 is the domain, so it is not part of the directory. Either have your path start with `//localhost:8090` (with or without `http:`), or don't include "localhost" at all. So, how about trying `"/enterprisesecvis/resources/flotr2_master/flotr2.js"`

Comment: That is, I am assuming "Project_Name" is the same as "enterprisesecvis" ;)

Comment: Mr Lister, I will try your recommendations. Thank you for your interest. I think the problem is not the wrong path, cause I check the formed path using Google Developer tools. As I said before option 1, 3 and 4 forms the correct path for JS file but can not load the existing file from that path.

Comment: Yeah sorry that was my bad, leaving the domain at the beginning of the path.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for the case of correct paths but not loading the js files. I also did the same trials for a simple js file other than flotr but nothing changed :(

Comment: If you're getting a 404 error then either the file isn't there, or the path is incorrect. This is very difficult to help resolve remotely as it's most likely going to be a very minor issue like a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added these lines to web.xml file and the problem is corrected. It wasn't related to the wrong definition of the path as I expected.

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Good Night :)